# Can not login using phpseclib with RSA keys?

Tags: php, openssh, phpseclib

I'm trying to use phpseclib to have an app executing remote commands on a linux server. I easily got it to work with username/password but I don't want to let that info in a plain text file so I want to use OpenSSH generated keys. Here is the buggy code.

```
<?php
include 'Crypt/RSA.php';
include 'Net/SSH2.php';

$key = new Crypt_RSA();
$key->loadKey('key');
echo file_get_contents('key');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('srv-test');
if (!$ssh->login('user', $key)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
echo $ssh->exec('ls');
?>
```

and the output is

```
$ php test_key.php

-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKCAQEAqcmSbXneDVQsMe/kjKxkaaqKPTN5GUawoeknWL20exQN4HqCAklE
FMUcOd48ypAj4CZc9baGtjbpC3zCRDRcatJQTWbsP/P4vSe7728JPcVa0PVmqyi0
YF5rRAnkcNVA1X4EGriYhLYGTjeEZMjvrubBBgAsYUaRbyYBauSpp7GqAP3/sVk6
YeNRrs8nOLFYdp1bAmAlSemzixYWQ466jeHAfevD06WwSLwD1fh6Dfyt5kvsUZGp
7KldtHwBKg/YE947YSwIFkUVOQkyx7+7BgnDhTo8sgiY4in0YK9PIC5o/gBnBqw9
eBUjNFHTQSv8gRTEP68NfYipgy2VmcNPAQIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----

Login Failed
```

the `key` file was generated with

```
ssh-keygen -f .ssh/id_rsa.pub -e -m pem
```

(the default format didn't work either) and I can normally login with the `id_rsa.pub` keyfile form the console. What am I missing ? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your post:

> ```
> $key = new Crypt_RSA();
> $key->loadKey('key');
> echo file_get_contents('key');
> ```

`$key->loadKey('key');` isn't expecting a filename - it's expecting the actual key. So if you're having to do `file_get_contents('key')` to show the actual key then you'll have to do `$key->loadKey(file_get_contents('key'))`.

Also, you need to supply `loadKey` with the private key - not the public key. It looks like you're not because the key you did post has `-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----` in it. The private key is needed because that's how you verify your identity. You sign with the private key, the server verifies with the public key.

Comment: That's what I was doing in the beggining then I switched to give it the filename. So it doesn't work either (and with both file formats).

Comment: @dev93 - you also need to supply `loadKey` with the private key - not the public key. It looks like you're not because the key you did post has `-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----` in it. The private key is needed because that's how you verify your identity. You sign with the private key, the server verifies with the public key.

Comment: @dev93 - also, if you want to test whether or not `Crypt_RSA` was able to successfully parse the key try doing `echo $key;`. That'll call the `__toString` magic method which'll basically recreate the key in whatever the default format is.

Comment: I don't know where was my head. Just changed to

   `$key->loadKey('/.ssh/id_rsa');`
and it worked like a charm. Thank you sooooo much